# pyqt5 open ftp url in file explorer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Iam trying to open ftp url in file explorer.

```
    url = QUrl("ftp://192.168.1.127:15010/intrusionfiles/detectionfiles/",QUrl.TolerantMode)
    url.setScheme("ftp")
    QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
```

When I try it this way it asks how I want it to open. How do I get it to open directly in file explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by starting explorer.exe using qprocess.

```
    p = QProcess()
    p.startDetached("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", ["ftp://admin:admin@192.168.1.127:15010/intrusionfiles/detectionfiles/21-09-21/"])
```

Comment: `startDetached` with that syntax is a static method, creating an instance for it is pointless, since it won't be used. You can just use `QProcess.startDetached(...)`.